# Laravel request is css not working with id

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using the following line of code to make the div active:

```
{{ Request::is('admin/customers') ? 'active_admin_menu' : null }}
```

This works great when the link is on admin/customers, but as soon as the link goes to admin/customers/123 then the link goes non active again.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try adding a wildcard

```
Request::is('admin/customers*')
```